# Requisição não funcionando no firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax

Eu estou fazendo uma requisição Ajax, onde ela funciona no Chrome perfeitamente porém no firefox não funciona.

Ele me diz que event não é definido

```
function pegarValor() {
        dado =  event.srcElement.innerText;

        var XMLHttp =  generateXMLHttp();
        XMLHttp.open("get", "classes/getData.php?result=" + dado, true);
        XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (XMLHttp.readyState == 4)
                if (XMLHttp.status == 200) {
                    data = XMLHttp.responseText.split("#");
                    if(XMLHttp.responseText == ""){

                        $(".conteudo-select").html("Não foi encontrado");
                    }else{
                        $("#txtRazaoSocial").val(data[0]);
                        $("#txtCNPJ").val(data[1]);

                        $(".conteudo-select").fadeOut(500);
                    }
                }
        };
        XMLHttp.send(null);

    }
```

Ai no HTML tem uma

```
<div onlick='pegarValor()'>
```

**Obs:** Eu tentando fazer o  $("#id").on('click',function(){ ... }) não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há muito tempo (acho que mais de uma década) o pessoal do Internet Explorer resolveu que seria uma boa ideia ter uma variável global chamada `event`, preenchida sempre com os dados do evento disparado.

Se isso foi mesmo uma boa ideia é questão de opinião. O que é fato é que os principais navegadores seguem essa idea, com exceção do Firefox. [Fonte: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event).

No seu caso, para que a função funcione no Firefox, você precisa declará-la para receber um parâmetro, dessa forma:

```
function pegarValor(event) {
    dado =  event.srcElement.innerText;
    // resto do código
```

E se a sua função for chamada na mão e não pela captura de um evento, você precisa montar um objeto com os dados que você quer e passá-lo explicitamente.

Comment: valeu cara, funcionou